# PayPal Auto Payment without logging in

Tags: paypal

I want to make a payment system in which users can connect their PayPal account to a website. In this step, login required.

When transaction occurs, without having to log in again, users can pay to the site.

This would be quite different from PayPal subscriptions -- just auto payment like upwork client account.

Comment: this is exactly what paypal "subscription" is made for. You get the permission by the user once and can charge that user without any action taken by him

Comment: No, subscriptions are for automatic payments of a set amount on a set schedule. This question, although poorly worded, appears to be for payments of arbitrary amounts at arbitrary points in time, i.e. "reference transactions", "future payments", or "vaulting"

Comment: This is not exactly subscription. Subscription is auto payment method during regular interval. I don't mean it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking seems to be a "Reference Transactions" solution.  It can be tested in sandbox, but to use it in live, the business account would need to be approved for this feature by PayPal. To do this the account owner would need to contact their PayPal account manager or PayPal's general [customer support](https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us) (*not* MTS), and explain the business need for this feature.

As far as implementing the solution, the only public documentation I'm aware of is for classic APIs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ec-set-up-reference-transactions/  .  Any newer API or vault solution does not appear to be publicly available at this time, but you could always contact PayPal's support and ask if there's something they'd rather you implement than those classic APIs. The more significant hurdle is the business approval for the feature mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's very helpful to me. But I would like ask more detail. You are saying it's necessary to make contract with paypal support for live step. I have checked some contract sites and found that only a few sites provide automatic payment system using paypal. And the most important thing is that I can't see doreference transaction in sandbox, too. I would like explain more detail about this.