# PayPal - Auto Pay

Tags: react-native, paypal

I am searching about integrate PayPal to a React Native app. I am able to make a payment using PayPal. Following, there is an idea but I don't know if PayPal allow us to do so.

The idea is: For example, I have an online shop "ABC", people add money to buy things later. If the money they have in store reach $10, PayPal will add $90 to shop "ABC" automatically without the approve.

Does PayPal allow us to do so?

I am really appreciated any helps from you guys.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you're asking. Where does this $90 come from ?

Comment: It's difficult to get approval for, but here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118454/2069605

Comment: @ArthurAttout: $90 is from customer. The money will transfer to online shop automatically if that customer has only $10 left in shop